# jquery issue while using media

Tags: jquery, html, media, soundcloud-stratus

I have stratus 2 beta running on my main index page and load in other pages using onclick event into a div. This works perfectly except when it comes to loading in a video feed from another page. There seems to be some kind of conflict.

Here are a number of snippets from my index page.

This loads the main player in

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
(function() {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    return $('body').stratus({
      theme: 'http://stratus.sc/themes/dark.css',
      buying: false,
      download: true,
      random: false,
      user: true,
      stats: true,
      popup: true,
      volume: 30,
      auto_play: true,
      links: 'https://soundcloud.com/ccpgames/eve-online-tiamat-2015-release, https://soundcloud.com/ccpgames/sets/eve-online-login-screen-music'
    });   });
}).call(this);
</script>
```

onclick event is as follows...

`<li> <a nohref Onclick="window.open('recruitment.html','page');">Recruitment</a> </li>`

code on the recruitment.html page is as follows.

`

```
<!--[if !IE]><!-->
<object id="mpa" type="application/x-ms-wmp" data="video/test.avi" width="720" height="540">
    <param name="src" value="video/test.avi" valuetype="ref" type="video/test.avi">
    <param name="autoStart" value="1">
    <param name="ShowControls" value="0">
    <param name="Showcontrols" value="false" />
    <param name="autoStart" value="True" />
    <param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
    <param name="ShowDisplay" value="0">
    <param name="ShowStatusBar" value="0">
    <param name="playcount" value="1">
    <param name="autoRewind" value="0">
    <param name="displaysize" value="0">
    <param name="stretchtofit" value="1">
    <param name="enableContextMenu" value="0">
    <param name="uiMode" value="none">
    <embed type="application/x-mplayer2" src="video/test.avi" width="720" height="540" autostart="true" pluginspage="http://www.microsoft.com/Windows/MediaPlayer/"></embed>
</object> 
<!--<![endif]-->
```

`

as you can see the recruitment page loads a video media, what I am trying to do is when this page is loaded into the main div from the menu, I need it to pause the stratus 2 beta player and play the video media... if possible resume the stratus 2 beta player once the page display div is next updated with new content.

At present the stratus 2 beta player continues to play, the media content box loads but no video plays....

When the page is loaded directly, eg not from the menu, it plays just fine, so it seems to be a conflict with the stratus 2 beta player.

If anyone could point me in the right direction to the code or help building the code I would be most grateful

Answer (score 0):

> I need it to pause the stratus 2 beta player

There is no pause method

> and play the video media...

Use an absolute path to the `data` or `src` attribute to avoid an unexpected context-sensitive path failure

**References**

- [stratus.js Source](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/peterchappy/Stratus-SoundCloudPlayer-v2.1/master/stratus.js)